# Выбрать по 10 случайных чисел из каждой категории

Tags: sql, статистика

Есть таблица в которой записаны случайные целые числа. Нужно группировать числа по сотнях и из каждой сотни выбрать по 10 случайных значений.

Вот пример запроса из таблички:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [ID]
  ,[Phone]
FROM [CallList].[dbo].[hundreds]
```

---

```
ID          Phone 
----------- ------
1           210001
2           210002
3           210003
4           210004
5           210006
6           210007
7           210008
8           210009
9           210010
10          210011
```

---

Далее я эволюционировал до:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hundr order by hundr) as 'num'
FROM (
SELECT id, phone, cast(phone/100 as int) as 'hundr' 
FROM [CallList].[dbo].[hundreds]) x
```

Как из того что вышло получить по 10 случайных чисел из каждой сотни?

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Пронумеруйте через row_number в partition и в group by добавьте сотни, ф-ция аналогичная random в sql есть. max(case when number = random then value end) позволит выбрать Приведите пример вашей выборки. За вас решение писать не будут.

Comment: @nick_n_a подправил вопрос. но все еще не понимаю как выбрать 10 рандомных из того что получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант, конечно же перед этим заменив YOURTABLE на нужную таблицу и * на нужный набор колонок.

NEWID() подходит лучше всего для генерации рандомного порядка в выборке. Потом нумеруем каждую строку в выборке, и последний шаг - выбираем первые 10 строк из каждой сотни.

**EDIT:**

Подправил ответ после правки вопроса. Опять же замените * на нужный набор колонок. Добавил сортировку по hundr и RandomId вначале, чтобы рандомизировать не всю выборку, а каждую сотню строк. Потом снова нумеруем результат и выбираем первые 10 из каждой сотни:

```
;WITH OrderedRandomSet
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    NEWID() AS RandomId, 
    CAST(phone/100 AS INT) AS 'hundr',
    * 
    FROM [CallList].[dbo].[hundreds]
    ORDER BY hundr, RandomId
)
,NumberedRandomSet 
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER(ORDER BY hundr, RandomId) AS RowNumber,
    *
    FROM OrderedRandomSet
)
SELECT * FROM NumberedRandomSet
WHERE (RowNumber % 100) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Comment: платформа  MS SQL. Боллее конкретизировал вопрос.

Comment: Подправил ответ.

Comment: Если помогло - пометьте как отвеченный :)